# Returning a json data from database using c# and wcf

Tags: c#, wcf

Good day everyone!
I am trying to make a program that returns Meeting details for a specific email address from the database. Now the problem is, I am trying to construct a JSON response using these:

```
[DataContract]
public class Meetings
{
    public string PresiderEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public List<MeetingDetails> Allmeeting { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class MeetingDetails
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public long MeetingId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string MeetingNumber {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string MeetingName {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string MeetingDescription {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public string MeetingDate {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public string MeetingVenue {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Order = 6)]
    public string TimeStarted {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Order = 7)]
    public string TimeEnded {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Order = 8)]
    public decimal CompletionRate {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Order = 9)]
    public string Remarks {get; set;}
}

public Meetings retrieveMeetingDetailsByEmail(string EmailAddress)
{
    SqlConnection EMTConnection2 = new SqlConnection();
    EMTConnection2.ConnectionString = constring;
    EMTConnection2.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr2;
    string EMTQuery2 = "Select * from dbo.Meeting where PresiderEmailAddress = @PresiderEmailAddress";
    SqlCommand EMTCommand2 = new SqlCommand(EMTQuery2, EMTConnection2);
    EMTCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PresiderEmailAddress", EmailAddress);

    dr2 = EMTCommand2.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr2.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr2.Read())
        {

            var meeting = new Meetings
              {
                  Allmeeting = new List<MeetingDetails>
                {
                  new MeetingDetails{MeetingId = Convert.ToInt64(dr2["MeetingId"]), MeetingNumber = dr2["MeetingNumber"].ToString(), MeetingName = dr2["MeetingName"].ToString(), MeetingDescription = dr2["MeetingDescription"].ToString(), MeetingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr2["MeetingDate"]).ToShortDateString().ToString(), MeetingVenue = dr2["MeetingVenue"].ToString(), TimeStarted = dr2["TimeStarted"].ToString(), TimeEnded = dr2["TimeEnded"].ToString(), CompletionRate = Convert.ToDecimal(dr2["CompletionRate"]), Remarks = dr2["Remarks"].ToString()}
                }
              };
        }
    }
    EMTConnection2.Close();
    dr2.Close();
}
```

The question is, how do I return all of the data to the client? It always tells me that the method should have a return value and I don't know where and what should I return.
 I'm really confused.

Comment: After all assignments in `new MeetingDetails { ... }`, you mean? And then at the end of the method you'll need a `return meeting;` which won't compile because `meeting` is out of scope, so you'll need to declare it at an outer scope, for example before the `if()`. Anyway please read [ask], "I'm confused" isn't really something we can answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. Still a newbie here. Yeah, after all assignments. Where should I put the return statement? I can't access the meeting variable.

Comment: At the end of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables would have scope only within the block. You should read some good c# materials [Variables and scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx). The next problem, functions declared with a return type should return an object of that type.

To help with your problem, change your method retrieveMeetingDetailsByEmail as below

```
public Meetings retrieveMeetingDetailsByEmail(string EmailAddress)
{
    using(SqlConnection EMTConnection2 = new SqlConnection())
    {
        string constring = ""; //Initialize connection string here
        EMTConnection2.ConnectionString = constring;
        EMTConnection2.Open();
        string EMTQuery2 = "Select * from dbo.Meeting where PresiderEmailAddress = @PresiderEmailAddress";
        using(SqlCommand EMTCommand2 = new SqlCommand(EMTQuery2, EMTConnection2))
        {
            EMTCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PresiderEmailAddress", EmailAddress);
            var meeting = new Meetings();
            meeting.PresiderEmailAddress = EmailAddress;

            using (SqlDataReader dr2 = EMTCommand2.ExecuteReader();
            {
                if (dr2.HasRows)
                {
                    meeting.Allmeeting = new List<MeetingDetails>();
                    while (dr2.Read())
                    {
                        meeting.Allmeeting.add(new MeetingDetails{MeetingId = Convert.ToInt64(dr2["MeetingId"]), MeetingNumber = dr2["MeetingNumber"].ToString(), MeetingName = dr2["MeetingName"].ToString(), MeetingDescription = dr2["MeetingDescription"].ToString(), MeetingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr2["MeetingDate"]).ToShortDateString().ToString(), MeetingVenue = dr2["MeetingVenue"].ToString(), TimeStarted = dr2["TimeStarted"].ToString(), TimeEnded = dr2["TimeEnded"].ToString(), CompletionRate = Convert.ToDecimal(dr2["CompletionRate"]), Remarks = dr2["Remarks"].ToString());
                    }
                }
                dr2.Close();
            }
            EMTConnection2.Close();
        }
    }

    return meeting;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm still new to the language. I'll test this code and see if it works. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You have not declare the `meeting` object properly

**EDIT:**
1. Create the Meeting object in outer scope
2. You have to return the meeting object at the end of the method.

```
public Meetings retrieveMeetingDetailsByEmail(string EmailAddress)
{
    SqlConnection EMTConnection2 = new SqlConnection();
    EMTConnection2.ConnectionString = constring;
    EMTConnection2.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr2;
    string EMTQuery2 = "Select * from dbo.Meeting where PresiderEmailAddress = @PresiderEmailAddress";
    SqlCommand EMTCommand2 = new SqlCommand(EMTQuery2, EMTConnection2);
    EMTCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PresiderEmailAddress",EmailAddress);

   dr2 = EMTCommand2.ExecuteReader();
   var meeting = new Meetings(); //declare here
   if (dr2.HasRows)
   {
       while (dr2.Read())
       {
            var meetingDetails = new MeetingDetails
            {  
                MeetingId = Convert.ToInt64(dr2["MeetingId"]), MeetingNumber = dr2["MeetingNumber"].ToString(), MeetingName = dr2["MeetingName"].ToString(), MeetingDescription = dr2["MeetingDescription"].ToString(), MeetingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr2["MeetingDate"]).ToShortDateString().ToString(), MeetingVenue = dr2["MeetingVenue"].ToString(), TimeStarted = dr2["TimeStarted"].ToString(), TimeEnded = dr2["TimeEnded"].ToString(), CompletionRate = Convert.ToDecimal(dr2["CompletionRate"]), Remarks = dr2["Remarks"].ToString()
            };
            meeting.AllMeetings.Add(meetingDetails);
       }
    }
    meeting.PresiderEmailAddress = EmailAddress; //add here 
    EMTConnection2.Close();
    dr2.Close();
    return meeting; // return the meeting object
}
```

Comment: Yeah, as what @Chris told me, my variable are out of the scope of my declarations. Thanks!